# Android libs error

Tags: java, android, sdk, parse-platform, buildpath

I am using Parse.com and I upgraded the parse SDK from 1.2.4 to 1.3.0. I have deleted the 1.2.4 files from the libs folder and pasted the 1.3.0 files to libs folder. When I am trying to run my app now it is crashing with no error. After debugging I found out that when I try to open any declaration of Parse class files it shows me this:
[image]

Here is the build path screenshot:
[image]

I have tried to clean the project, closed and opened eclipse.

I am stucked! Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you please share the logcat stack-trace snippet when you get the error ? Also did you try uninstalling the application  first before deploying the changed application ?

Comment: the log cat doesn't show any error, the crash is errorless. I have tried to uninstall and install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, but it was not related to the libs file or to the build path. The problem was in the manifast, had to remove android:noHistory="true" from my activity tag and the every thing worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Please verify the BuildPath as well.

```
Right Click on the Project -> BuildPath -> Configure Build Path
```

Check to see there is `.jar` files or not. If there are no `.jar` files, Upload using "Add Jars" button from your `libs` directory. Once Build Path is configured, clean and run the Project. Hope this will help you.

Comment: I have added image of my build path. it seems ok (or not)

Comment: Yes, its correct. Now, Clean and try to run the project. If any issues, let me know.

Comment: same thing, the app crashes with no error. When i try to see Parse declaration it shows me source not found

Comment: Switch the Eclipse Workspace to different path. I think the problem is with Eclipse.....

Comment: how do I do this (Switch the Eclipse Workspace)? I have tried it on 2 different computers.

Comment: No. Do it in a single System. In Eclipse, Go to `File -> Switch Workspace -> Select the Path`. Then `import` your project folder using `import` option in `File`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32317/discussion-between-vlad-ioffe-and-avadhani-y)

Comment: I found the solution, but it was not related to the libs file or to the build path. The problem was in the manifast, had to remove `android:noHistory="true"` and the every worked fine. I will post it as an answer, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

From your figure you posted, it just that your editor cannot find source for your jar file. But in your figure i do see javadoc. In the same page you will see a button called "Attach source". You can click that button to locate manually your javadoc. With this you should be able to go to source code.

Comment: I think there is no source file. the only files there are (in the Parse.com android sdk) are as seen in the libs folder.